# Override child ngOnInit method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, inheritance

I want to add code to child's ngOnInit method from a parent class.
Can I somehow do something similar to this?

```
export class Child extends Parent {
   constructor(){
      super(this.ngOnInit);
   }
   ngOnInit(){
      console.log('Child onInit');
   }
}
```

And Parent:

```
export class Parent {
   constructor(childOnInitMethod: any){}
   ngOnInit(){
      console.log('Parent added code to child onInit');
      this.childOnInitMethod.apply(this, arguments)
   }
}
```

The problem is that on the child constructor I do not have "this" available.

**UPDATE:** Find here the current code

For now, this is what I've done. Child class extends parent's ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy. What I want to achieve is to avoid calling parent "super.subscribeEvents();" like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   window.onresize = () => console.log('resizing');
   super.subscribeEvents();
}
```

What I want to do is to add code to the Child's ngOnInit from Parent.
These are the classes:

```
export class DatatablePage extends EventSubscriber {
   @Output() onLoadRow: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
   public gridApi: GridApi;
   constructor(
    events: Events
   ) {
    super(events, [
        { eventName: 'datatable:updateList', callbackFunction: () => this.onLoadRow.emit() },
        { eventName: 'datatable:resizeTable', callbackFunction: () => this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit() }
    ])
   }

   ngOnInit() {
       window.onresize = () => console.log('resizing');
       super.subscribeEvents();
   }
}
```

And Parent:

```
export class EventSubscriber {


constructor(
    private events: Events,
    public eventSubscriptions: EventObject[]
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeEvents();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribeEvents();
}

subscribeEvents() {
    this.eventSubscriptions.forEach((eventSubscription: EventObject) => {
        this.events.subscribe((eventSubscription.eventName), eventSubscription.callbackFunction)
    });
}

unsubscribeEvents() {
    this.eventSubscriptions.forEach((eventSubscription: EventObject) => {
        this.events.unsubscribe((eventSubscription.eventName), eventSubscription.callbackFunction)
    });
}
}
```

Comment: you need to use `@Input()` to communicate with the child

Comment: you are saying that u don't want to call `subscribeEvent` form child's `ngOnInit` method ??

Comment: That's it, I want the parent to add code to child's ngOnInit. This way classes extending EventSubscriber don't need to to care about calling parent if they have a custom ngOnInit

Answer (score 1):

the below solution should work.

```
class Parent {
   constructor(){}
   ngOnInit(){
      console.log('Parent added code to child onInit');
      this.ngOnInit()
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    ngOnInit() {
      console.log('Child onInit');
    }
    invokeSuperOnInit() { 
        super.ngOnInit();
    }
}

const a = new Child();
a.invokeSuperOnInit();
```

Execution:

> 1. Created object of Child Class and assigned to a.
> 2. calling invokeSuperOnInit Method on the object a.
> 3. ngOnInit of the Parent is invoked.
> 4. In the parent NgOninit We are calling ngOnInit of the Child. The Child ngOnInit is invoked because "this" will always stay same through out
>      the hierarchy.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to invoke parents ngOnInit manually. I updated the question with the concrete classes to show my closest approach.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call methods on your child you need to add it in your parent's `.component` in the following way:

```
@ViewChild(Child) child: Child;
```

After your parent and child are instantiated you can use `this.child.anyFunction();`

**An alternative** is to use `@Input` for your child like:

```
@Input() test: number;
```

The parent's view should look like this:

```
<child [test]="example"></child>
```

While you define the variable in your component:

```
example: number;

ngOnInit() {
    this.example = 1;
}
```

Have also a look on ngOnChanges.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. The answer is more related to class inheritance, rather than angular component structure. @Punith Mithra is in the right spot